# Moving to .Net 4.6 caused an overflow exception

Tags: c#, c++, .net, intptr

I have several projects (managed and unmanaged) which run on 32 and 64 bit operating systems with 
.Net 4.0 for a long time. 
When we upgraded to .Net 4.6 (4.0 --> 4.6) and run this code:

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure(DataInfo, info);
DataInfo = (IntPtr)((int)DataInfo + Internal_Const.DataInfoSize);
```

We got the following error:

> Proj1 fails on OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow

we solved the issue by casting to long, i.e:

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure(DataInfo, info); 
DataInfo = (IntPtr)((long)DataInfo + Internal_Const.DataInfoSize);
```

so, my question is why did it help? and why did it crush only after moving to .Net 4.6?
Our theory is that since it’s a 64 bit system, the pointer can point to memory further than the 32 bit and when trying to cast it to int it fails.

However, we have many 64 bit systems running for many years and it never failed before moving to .Net 4.6.

Thanks.

Comment: It was just a time-bomb ready to go off at any time.  Your project's Platform target and your Windows version are more relevant to setting it off.  Specific to 4.6 is that the C# compiler now has the /highentropyva option turned on, that does increase the odds you'll get a high address even on old Win versions.